# Error while compiling through cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin, command-prompt, windows64

I am using cygwin for 64 bit Windows but while compiling a makefile I end up with this error

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: you use bashisms in your Makefile, but don't set the shell (`/bin/sh` reports the error). Just state

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

at the top of the Makefile.

Comment: Thank you....But was able to fix the error...there was some bug in the directory inclusion part of the makefile...