# Error using `make` on cygwin for Windows 64 bit: /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin, mingw, charniak-parser

When attempting to compile [this project](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/) using make in cygwin64, I encounter this error:

```
carolyns@ugrpc /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Discourse_Parser_Dist/bllip-parser-master/bllip-parser-master
$ make
C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make -C first-stage/PARSE parseIt
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make -C first-stage/PARSE parseIt'
make: *** [PARSE] Error 1
```

Some sleuthing suggests the issue could be my bash version, but I am using V4 as seems recommended

```
carolyns@ugrcpc /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Discourse_Parser_Dist/bllip-parser-master/bllip-parser-master
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

as well as make V3.81

```
carolyns@ugrpc /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Discourse_Parser_Dist/bllip-parser-master/bllip-parser-master
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have also added `SHELL := /bin/bash` as suggested by [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851661/error-while-compiling-through-cygwin)

Other sources of this error seem unrelated to my situation ([echo problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890419/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-with-gnu-shell-function)).

I've tried this using MinGW64 as well with the same result. I've also tried [moving the folder out of the Program Files directory](https://community.particle.io/t/problems-building-develop-branch-locally/14331), with the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you feel compelled to downvote this question please let me know how I can improve it or what information I should be searching for in addition to what I've already tried. I'm no expert in Make and this is my first time developing on a windows machine so I do apologize if some of the things I've added seem irrelevant or extraneous.

Comment: It's been pointed out to me it might be unhappy with the `Program Files (x86)` in the path to GnuWin32 where make lives -- I am trying to fix that now.

Comment: Why are you not using the `make` for cygwin? Install it using the cygwin setup app. You do not need to use any of the GnuWin32 software when you are using cygwin. Just install the cygwin packages you need, and take GnuWin32 out of your path when using cygwin.

Comment: **See Also** [Cygwin unexpected token `(` on cd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15080184/1366033)

Answer (score 3):

### Fixed

It was unhappy with my make path including `Program Files (x86)`. I moved make and forced it to use the new path and got a shiny new error.

Hope this helps another windows newbie.

Comment: space and parenthesis in the PATH are usually a recipe for problems